# CakePHP 3.6: Change submit button label

Tags: php, button, cakephp, label

I tried to change the label of a `Submit` button with no luck:

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), array('name' => 'Create')) ?>
```

How I can change it?

Comment: Use `$this->Form->label('name', 'Your username');` to create a label. (On a sidenote: `button` element doesn't need a label)

Comment: @kerbholz but now the button shows Submit as a label, how I can change it to show 'Create' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the text from Submit to Create:

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Create')) ?>
```

It will generate a button that looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this :

```
$options = [];
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Create'), $options) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 4.x, you can use

```
<?= $this->Form->submit("Login",['class'=>'any-css-class-if-needed']); ?>
```

For reference: [Creating Submit Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-submit-elements)